# Install PostgreSQL 11.1 on Debian Stretch with PostgreSQL Debian (9.6)

Tags: postgresql, debian

I have a production machine running debian strecth that I do not want to mess up. I have an app that requires postgres 11 and I'm not sure about a thing. Does the installation from the official postgres debian repo install as an extra server or does it replace the existing 9.6 verssion on debian?

I have tried to dump from version 11 and restore in 9.6 but it throws an error on creation of a sequence:

```
psql:fas-schema.sql:125: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
```

Just need to be sure 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple versions of PostgreSQL one the same host, you should use official packages provided by [PGDG](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/). All the [currently supported versions](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/) are available.

Though, these packages are not including tools provided by the Debian project, such as [pg_ctlcluster](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/postgresql-common/pg_ctlcluster.1.en.html) or [pg_lsclusters](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/postgresql-common/pg_lsclusters.1.en.html).